# NASM setting in Vistual Studio13

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, nasm

I am creating a library, which require some assembly level code.
I am using using NASM to write and integrate my .asm file.
Now the problem is, I already have a project created in VS13. Now I want to add and integrate an assembly level code to my project.
I have already added a .asm file in my source directory, but when I am trying to run my test case, the compiler is unable to find my assembly code.

I want to know how can I link my .asm file with my .c file.

Structure of my project:

->Project1(Generates a Library)

--->Source

----->File1.c

----->File2.c

----->nasm.asm

->Project2 (Test case to use the library and generate .exe)

-->Source

---->main.c

Now, nasm.asm binaries should get attached with the .lib generated by project1
and Project2 should able to access project1.lib

Apologize if question is bit unclear, its a bit complex for me to make it clear in written. Please let me know if you want any clarification or extra information.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of you assembly files:

1. Right click it in the *Solution Explorer* and choose *Properties*
2. **Make sure** the selected *Configuration* is either *All Configurations* or the configuration you are using (this bites me every time!)
3. In the *Configuration Properties*>*General* change the *Item type* to **Custom Build Tool**
4. From the *Configuration Properties*>*Custom Build Tool*>*General* set the following items:

   - **Command Line**. Use this as an example: `nasm -fwin32 "%(FullPath)" -o %(Filename).obj`
   - **Outputs**. This is necessary, VS check for this files. I usually use `%(Filename).obj`.
   - **Link Objects**. `Yes`. If you name your output files with *obj* extension they are automatically included in the link phase.

To check that you set everything right, select your assembly file, right click and choose *Compile*.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Although compilation is successful, but binary is not getting generated.. I have hard coded the Output file path to my Debug directory but still I can't find it anywhere..

Comment: @MitulShrivastava by binary you mean the object file from nasm or the whole binary from VS?

Comment: Binaries for nasm only.                                                                                             I tried to build it as a separate project and for that project binaries were generated..

Comment: @MitulShrivastava I don't know how to help you :( I have tried it again and with my VS2013 I have a obj file from nasm generated in my project directory (not in the debug one)

Comment: My bad.. I have given the command line for different project.. So it was not executing the .asm at all..                  But, now its saying "  'nasm' is not recognized as an internal or external command," I have included the nasm.target file in Build->Build Customization..

Comment: @MitulShrivastava you have to add the nasm directory to the path environment variable (if you search the string *add directory to path environment variable windows* on google it will answer) or you can specify the full path to the nasm executable (ie like `C:\nasm\nasm.exe`) in the *Command line* item

Comment: I recommend using the PATH environment variable to find NASM, since it will be installed in different locations on different systems. Typical locations: `C:\nasm\ ` (custom install),  `C:\Program Files\ ` (64-bit build of NASM), and  `C:\Program Files (x86)\ ` (32-bit build of NASM).